# isScrollContainer doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the next layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button1"

            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button2"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button3"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I set android:isScrollContainer to "true" so that when the soft keyboard is shown, EditText will shrink and we can still see "Submit" button. 
 
But when I run the project on my device, the soft keyboard hides this button.
 
Please tell me what is wrong.
**Edit** I've just tested it on my emulator and it works pretty fine and I'm sure it worked on my device as well. But something on the tablet must have been updated and have changed the behaviour.
**Screenshots** NVIDIA TegraNote-P1640 Android 4.4.2 (API19)
[image: keyboard shown] [image: keyboard hidden]

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping everything in a LinearLayout and set fillViewport property for Scroll View to true.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping everything inside a `<ScrollView>...</ScrollView>` worked for me.